# can’t find file saved with write.csv() in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Since yesterday, my R studio's `write.csv()` code doesn't work. When I use this code, I can find the file in R studio, but it doesn't appear in my PC's file explorer. I can only see it on my R studio.

(But in VS code, it worked. And in R Studio, it worked until yesterday.) Has anyone got a same problem as me?

Comment: Hey, welcome on SO!
First check: Did you add a file extension to the filename? (eg. "mytable.csv"). Maybe Explorer only shows files with certain extensions. 
And second, I have to ask this: Is your R Session in the same directory your explorer is showing?
check your current working directory with `getwd()`.

Comment: "I can find the file in R Studio" -- do you mean you see it in the Files pane of RStudio or something else? If so, you should be able to click More - Show Folder in New Window to open the same directory in file explorer.

Comment: yes I already do getwd() and I clicked everything. Maybe I should reinstall R studio. Thanks for the cooment.

Comment: This is a strange problem. Can you post the code you used to create the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out RStudio was exporting the .csv into the file location as the script I was using rather than the working directory I had set. I solved this just by specifying the location.

ie:

```
write.csv(df, "/Users/User/Documents/df.csv")
```